# How to check if a download process is complete

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

My application will parse a XML file from my web server then download the files. My application will get the contents of "URL" from in XML file and download it using Common-IO's FileUtils. My problem is, how do I know that my download process is done or not. There is a lot of "URL" in my XML file.

Here is some part of my code:

```
private Proxy proxy = Proxy.NO_PROXY;
    public void downloadLibrary()
        {
            System.out.println("Start downloading libraries from server...");
            try
            {
                URL resourceUrl = new URL("http://www.example.com/libraries.xml");
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(resourceUrl.openConnection(proxy).getInputStream());
                NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("Contents");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeLst.getLength(); i++)
                {
                    Node node = nodeLst.item(i);

                    if (node.getNodeType() == 1)
                    {
                        Element element = (Element)node;
                        String key = element.getElementsByTagName("Key").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                        File f = new File(launcher.getWorkingDirectory(), key);
                        downloadFile("http://www.example.com/" + key, f, "libraries");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error was found when trying to download libraries file " + e);
            }

        }

        public void downloadFile(final String url, final File path, final String fileName)
        {
            SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>()
            {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
                {
                    launcher.println("Downloading file " + fileName + "...");
                    try
                    {
                        URL fileURL = new URL(url);
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(fileURL.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Cannot download file : " + fileName + " " + e);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                public void done()
                {
                    System.out.println(fileName + " had downloaded sucessfully");

                }
            };
            worker.execute();
        }
```

Comment: Please include the code you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send each download with one thread, which I recomend, You have severals possibilities.

Use of `Future` and `FutureTask` to wait until all the threads are done.

To use `thread.join()` to wait until the thread stops.

Comment: I hate lazy people :S

Comment: @RaminBoza Hahaha, you are the one who is lazy. You dont want to post example code. But never mind, I will try it myself :)

Comment: Am I the lazy? I don't have example code at hand to post it and would do the same as you, google it. So this is out of my business right now, your google search would be as good as mine.